# Can't resize treeview control in vb.net web page VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, resize, treeview

Have looked through the forums and can't find a solution to my particular problem.  I'm inserting a treeview (which loads as a local file explorer) into an aspx web page using vs 2013 and it won't allow me to adjust the width of it.  Tried common solutions like programatically changing the style="max-width:10px" property in the treeview, put it inside a panel, div, gridview and table just for kicks.  Also, using original .ico files as the images and sizing is also ineffective.  Have tried populating a placeholder with a programmed treeview and it shows the same results.  I think the problem is my master page style for the "Content" is stretching this to the max size.  Any way to override this for this particular page?  Can't even shrink it with the box resizing ticks around it in the designer.  Would like it to be set to a normal size so it's not different for every user at runtime.  Thanks!

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" Runat="Server">
<span class="auto-style1"><strong>Documentation
<br />
</strong></span>Upload a file to the database
<br /><asp:FileUpload ID="Browse" runat="server" Width="464px" />
<br /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" />
<br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="max-width:100px">
    <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView" runat="server" Width="229px">
    </asp:TreeView></asp:Panel>
<br />

</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Comment: can you put the html that renders in a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle? haha can you please elaborate?

Comment: sorry, https://jsfiddle.net/ is commonly used for html/css/javascript questions.  allows you to create a minimal test case to isolate your issue and share it

Comment: ok thanks i will try to get that working.  probably would be useful in the future too.